# save colour selector with local storage

Tags: javascript, html

so im trying to save colour selector to local storage so it will save the users selection after refreshing the page

this is a snippet of my code so far, if i remove the localstorage code from the script it will change colours but wont save the selection.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const colorOption = e.target.closest('.color-option');
    if (!colorOption) return;
    
    // unselect currently selected color options
    document.querySelectorAll('.color-option').forEach(colorOption => colorOption.classList.remove('is-selected'));
    colorOption.classList.add('is-selected');
    
    const color = colorOption.dataset.color;
    
    let root = document.documentElement;
    root.style.setProperty('--primary-color', color);

    localStorage.setItem(".color-option", "--primary-color");
    localStorage.getItem("--primary-color");
    
  });
```

```css
body {
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
}

.color-option {
  height:35px;
  width: 35px;
  list-style: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 7px;
  transition: .2s;
  cursor: pointer;
  &:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  }
  &.is-selected {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  }
}

.color-option:nth-child(1) { background: #3485fd }
.color-option:nth-child(2) { background: #002C5F }
.color-option:nth-child(3) { background: #00AFD8 }
.color-option:nth-child(4) { background: #5B1F69 }
.color-option:nth-child(5) { background: #FF5F1F }
.color-option:nth-child(6) { background: #ff00e2 }
```

```html
<body>
<ul class="color-grid">
    <li class="color-option is-selected" data-color="#3485fd"></li>
    <li class="color-option" data-color="#002C5F"></li>
    <li class="color-option" data-color="#00AFD8"></li>
    <li class="color-option" data-color="#5B1F69"></li>
    <li class="color-option" data-color="#FF5F1F"></li>
    <li class="color-option" data-color="#ff00e2"></li>
    
</ul>
</body>
```

can't quite figure out what im doing wrong hopefully someone can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. As the other answer points out, you are not actually storing the selected color value.

You can think of localStorage as a store for key-value pairs. The syntax to set an item would be something like:

```js
localStorage.setItem(<key>,<value>)
```

Where both key and value are strings. In order to store the user's color choice you'd have to do something like:

```js
localStorage.setItem("selectedColor","#adadad")
```

Another missing piece is perhaps the code to load the previously selected color on page load.

PS: If you are trying to run this code in a sandbox (like the stack overflow code editor) you may not be able to access localStorage due to Cross Origin policies. Using localStorage in cases like this will throw an error (which may be why it works if you remove the localStorage part)

See sample implementation below:

```js
const LS_COLOR_KEY = 'selected-color';

function selectColor(color){
  document.querySelectorAll('.color-option').forEach(function(node){node.classList.remove('is-selected')});
  document.querySelector('.color-option[data-color="'+color+'"]').classList.add('is-selected')
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--primary-color", color);
  localStorage.setItem(LS_COLOR_KEY, color);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  // Retrieve and select any previously stored color
  const storedColor = localStorage.getItem(LS_COLOR_KEY) || '#577590';
  selectColor(storedColor);
})

document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  const colorOption = e.target.closest('.color-option');
    if (!colorOption) return;
   selectColor(colorOption.dataset.color);
})
```

```css
:root {
  --primary-color: transparent;
}

.color-option > .swatch {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  margin: 0 0.25rem;
  display: inline-block;
}

.color-option {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0.25rem 0;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.color-option.is-selected{
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.selected-color {
  background: var(--primary-color);
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="options">
  <ul id="color-list">
  <li data-color="#577590" class="color-option"><div class="swatch" style="background:#577590">&nbsp;</div>Queen Blue</li>
  <li data-color="#F3CA40" class="color-option"><div class="swatch" style="background:#F3CA40"></div>Maize Crayola</li>
  <li data-color="#F08A4B" class="color-option"><div class="swatch" style="background:#F08A4B"></div>Mango Tango</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="selected-color"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for explaining why it wouldn't work in the code snippet, i wasn't sure if it was a stack overflow issue or not :),the code works on the home page of my site, when clicking into another page ( about, etc ) the primary-color reverts back to transparent, but when changing the colour and refreshing the home page the colour remains, is there any way to extend the selected colour from the homepage to other pages?

Comment: You would need the code(and styles) that sets the css variable to the color from localStorage on document load on every page that you want to use this feature on. The key should be the same across pages if you want them to be the same color. Another thing to consider is that the contents of localStorage is isolated to the domain of the page. So if you are not running a local server (http://localhost...) and using file://... to open the pages (or if your pages are on different domains), you may not see the same localStorage values as each page will have it's own isolated copy.

Comment: hmm i see, and is that a difficult thing to do? i'm pretty new at js so it might just be beyond me and might have to drop it but i'm thinking id be taking the selectColor(storedColor); which is refering to the "const storedColor = localStorage.getItem(LS_COLOR_KEY) || '#577590'; "  and adding a on load to it? 

something like window.onload = selectColor(storedColor);

also im using a localhost so its not isolating the pages i think lol.

Comment: No no - it's probably as simple as putting all this in a separate js file (say, `main.js`) and using the `<script src="main.js" />` tag on every page that you want it. It's a little hard for me to go into details without knowing the specifics of how you've set up your files and server etc. The sample code for actually running it when the page is loaded is already in the snippet above. you just need to put it on every page that you need it. `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){...})`
Make it work on your home and use the same thing on other pages :) You got this!

Comment: ahh i see, i was playing around with it more & i created a custom html block for individual pages and it seemed to work but as soon as i take out the html code it breaks,  server is just a wamp server ( all default settings ), the site is a moodle site pieced together using mustache template files, so ill just play around with it to make a theme selection popout window in a mustache file and hopefully that will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

please check below

```
localStorage.setItem('bgcolor', 'red');
localStorage.getItem('bgcolor');
```

now look at your code, you have used **.color-option** as keyName,

but used another keyName in getItem **--primary-color** which is wrong.

```
localStorage.setItem(".color-option", "--primary-color");
localStorage.getItem("--primary-color");
```

it should be

```
localStorage.setItem(".color-option", "--primary-color-value");
localStorage.getItem(".color-option");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I get what you want really! but if you want to store the selected color in local storage and bring it back on every load you can save the actual value of the color and on every load, you will set the root property of the (--primary-color) to the value you stored. Like this

In your js file

```
let root = document.documentElement;

document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

  const colorOption = e.target.closest(".color-option");

  if (!colorOption) return;

  // unselect currently selected color options
  document
    .querySelectorAll(".color-option")
    .forEach((colorOption) => colorOption.classList.remove("is-selected"));
  colorOption.classList.add("is-selected");

  const color = colorOption.dataset.color;

  root.style.setProperty("--primary-color", color);

  localStorage.setItem("selected-color", color);
});

window.onload = () => {
  root.style.setProperty(
    "--primary-color",
    localStorage.getItem("selected-color")
  );
};
```

I hope that solves what you want. thanks

Comment: so i've added a  ( --primary-color) property to some elements (text/ boxes etc) so when the user logins in they can select a colour then it will change those elements to the selected colours ( like user colour themes) i tried out your snippet and it kind of works, however it seems to hide the navigation menu text.

Comment: @DeanHoward
hm...... there is no navigation menu text in your snippet above. So if you add a new one I think you should consider what elements should have the property (--primary-color) so that it will be a nice looking element and don't effects on contrast of other elements. Thanks.